# Is there any way to set max-retry on service being executed by job scheduler in moqui

Tags: moqui

I am having one service which executes once a day and while executing if it fails/hasError it keeps retrying. I am using 'ServiceJob' entity to schedule, but here I didn't find the option to set max retry. Also on service def/implementation. Any direction to look into?

Any help or suggestion would really be appreciable
Thank you